# How to calculate a formula and add a row in data table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a data from database in a DaTaTable Object and i am performing a row calculation based on some formula defined in a list of string but unfortunately i am ending up with wrong calculation because Sequence of rows value does not match with given formula so calculations going wrong
For e.x ( Income before pipeline, depr/amort and MSR )= Net Production Income - Total Personal Cost - Other Cost + Service Fee Income

For that in a loop  first value is coming from datatable is Total Personal Cost and second is Other Cost third is Service Fee Income and in last Net Production Income. which form this formula
Income before pipeline, depr/amort and MSR = Total Personal Cost - Other Cost + Service Fee Income + Net Production income.

Please give me a solution and in that particular below code this code is performing row calculation for given formula

```
for (int P = 0; P < dt.Rows.Count; P++)
{                                
        rowName = dt.Rows[P]["GLDescription"].ToString();

        AddColume[0] = "";
        if (AddColume.Contains(rowName))
        {
            int l = 1;

            var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];

            if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))
            {

                    if (Expression[index] == "+")
                    {
                        totalRow += Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                    }
                    else if (Expression[index] == "-")
                    {
                        totalRow -= Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                    }

                index++;                                            
            }
        }
        else if (AddColume.Contains(rowName) && AddColume.Contains("self"))
        {
            var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];
            if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))
            {
                decimal CurrentValue = Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                dt.Rows[P][j] = CurrentValue * -1;
            }
        }


}
```

for you support i have this code

```
List<string> lstGrouping = new List<string>();
lstGrouping.Add("Volume↔Volume↔Volume↔Sigular");
lstGrouping.Add("Units↔Units↔Units↔Sigular");
lstGrouping.Add("Blank↔Blank↔Sigular");
lstGrouping.Add("Total Production Revenue↔Secondary-Net (Sell - Buy +/- Hedge)↔Branch Brokered Loan Income↔add");
lstGrouping.Add("Total Direct Costs↔Deed Recording↔Provisions for Loan Losses↔add");
lstGrouping.Add("Net Production Income↔Total Production Revenue↔Total Direct Costs↔+$-");
lstGrouping.Add("Total Personnel Costs↔Accounting Dept↔Employer payroll tax exp↔add");
lstGrouping.Add("Total G&A Costs and Other↔Bank Fees↔Provisions for Branch Losses↔add");
lstGrouping.Add("Servicing Fee Income↔Servicing Fee Income , net of expenses↔Servicing Fee Income , net of expenses↔Sigular");
lstGrouping.Add("Income before pipeline, depr/amort and MSR↔Net Production Income↔Total Personnel Costs↔Total G&A Costs and Other↔Servicing Fee Income↔+$+$-$-");
lstGrouping.Add("Other items Total↔Servicing Fee Income , net of expenses↔Depreciation Expense↔add");
lstGrouping.Add("Net Income↔Income before pipeline, depr/amort and MSR↔Other items Total↔+$+");
for (int i = 0; i < lstGrouping.Count; i++)
{

    var AddColume = lstGrouping[i].Split('↔');

    var Expression = AddColume[(AddColume.Length) - 1].Split('$');
    int startindex = 0;
    int Endindex = 0;

    foreach (DataRow DR in dt.Rows)
    {
        string GlDescription = DR["GLDescription"].ToString();
        if (GlDescription.Trim() == AddColume[1].Trim())
            startindex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(DR);
        else if (GlDescription.Trim() == AddColume[2].Trim())
            Endindex = dt.Rows.IndexOf(DR);
    }
    DataRow NewDR = dt.NewRow();
    if (Expression[0] == "add")
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(NewDR, Endindex + 1);
    else if (Expression[0] == "Sigular")
    {
        Endindex = 1;
    }
    else
        dt.Rows.Add(NewDR);
    DataRow level1Row = dtLevel1.NewRow();
    dtLevel1.Rows.Add(level1Row);
    if (startindex != null && Endindex != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            string ColName = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName;
            if (ColName != "GLDescription" && ColName != "GLDescriptionId")
            {
                decimal totalRow = 0;
                if (Expression[0] == "add")
                {
                    for (int K = startindex; K <= Endindex; K++)
                    {
                        var DRValue = dt.Rows[K][j];
                        if (DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value)
                            DRValue = 0;
                        if (Expression[0].Contains("add"))
                            totalRow += Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                    }
                }
                else if (Expression[0] == "Sigular")
                {
                    int KeyValue = startindex;
                    var DRValue = dt.Rows[KeyValue][j];
                    if (DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value)
                        DRValue = 0;
                    totalRow += Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                }
                else
                {

                    int index = 0;
                    int paraindex = 0;
                    string rowName;
                    for (int P = 0; P < dt.Rows.Count; P++)
                    {                                
                            rowName = dt.Rows[P]["GLDescription"].ToString();

                            AddColume[0] = "";
                            if (AddColume.Contains(rowName))
                            {
                                int l = 1;

                                var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];

                                if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))
                                {

                                        if (Expression[index] == "+")
                                        {
                                            totalRow += Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                                        }
                                        else if (Expression[index] == "-")
                                        {
                                            totalRow -= Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                                        }

                                    index++;                                            
                                }
                            }
                            else if (AddColume.Contains(rowName) && AddColume.Contains("self"))
                            {
                                var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];
                                if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))
                                {
                                    decimal CurrentValue = Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                                    dt.Rows[P][j] = CurrentValue * -1;
                                }
                            }


                    }

                }

                NewDR[ColName] = totalRow;
                level1Row[ColName] = totalRow;
            }
            else if (ColName == "GLDescription")
            {
                NewDR[ColName] = AddColume[0];
                level1Row[ColName] = AddColume[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
dtLevel2 = dt;

if (level == "lev1")
    return dtLevel1;
else if (level == "lev2")
    return dt;
else
    return null;
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use datatable?

Comment: Hi Chetan YES because data is coming from database, BUT IF you have any other suggestions than tell me  rowName = dt.Rows[P]["GLDescription"].ToString();

        AddColume[0] = "";
        if (AddColume.Contains(rowName))
        {
            int l = 1;

            var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];

            if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))
            { if you see that rowName is comming from dt and thats not match with my sequence

Comment: I would create a class with appropriate properties and populate the property values with the data coming from the database. That way I have better control over which property to use for calculation and also I don't need to worry about the sequence of the data.

Comment: Basically what i need is what ever i give formula in list that should perform calculation in sequence with my formula.

Comment: your formulae are complex. I am still in process of understanding your code. Give me some time I will see if I can find something better.

Comment: OK I can explain you it simply that

Comment: The code you can see in first part is the main code where calculation is performed

Comment: 'for (int P = 0; P < dt.Rows.Count; P++)
{     rowName = dt.Rows[P]["GLDescription"].ToString();
        AddColume[0] = "";
        if (AddColume.Contains(rowName))
        {int l = 1;
var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];
            if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))            {

                    if (Expression[index] == "+")
                    {
                        totalRow += Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
                    }
                    else if (Expression[index] == "-")
                    {totalRow -= Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);}'

Comment: I am getting that rowName from dt like this  'rowName = dt.Rows[P]["GLDescription"].ToString();'

Comment: and then checking that rowName with my formula if it contains

Comment: AddColume[0] = "";
        if (AddColume.Contains(rowName))
        {

Comment: var AddColume[] have the values defined in my list string formula like this 'lstGrouping.Add("Income before pipeline, depr/amort and MSR↔Net Production Income↔Total Personnel Costs↔Total G&A Costs and Other↔Servicing Fee Income↔+$+$-$-");'

Comment: and for suppose i have values in my dt like this Volume
Units
Secondary-Net-Sell-Buy+/-Hedge
Cost to sell to Fannie
Interest Income, net of Interest Expense
SL Fees
National Processing Center
Accounting Fee Income
Branch Brokered Loan Income
Total Production Revenue
Deed Recording
TotalPersonlCost

Comment: Then Coming Other Cost Service Fee Net Production Income

Comment: So i will get IN my rowname fir TotalPersonalCost and for that rowName i am performing this calculation 'if (AddColume.Contains(rowName))
        {
            int l = 1;

            var DRValue = dt.Rows[P][j];

            if (!(DRValue == null || DRValue == DBNull.Value))
            {

                    if (Expression[index] == "+")
                    {
                        totalRow += Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
            }
                    else if (Expression[index] == "-")                {
               totalRow -= Convert.ToDecimal(DRValue);
             }'

Comment: So it will calculate first what ever rowname i am getting in my Data Table

Comment: Please answer if you can i am still waiting.

Comment: Sorry... I was stuck somewhere else... I need some more information about the code you shared above. Which code block gets executed first? Also in the first code block I see variables `j`, `dt`, `index`, `expression`,  being used but it's nowhere declared. Same way in the second code block variables `level`, `dtdevel2`, `dtlevel1` are not declared anywhere.